# Tidio Chat - no longer installed but still trying to pull .js

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I installed Tidio Chat for wordpress then uninstalled it. It is still however trying to retrive .js code. It's adding 9-10 seconds on my site load time.

www.ivebeangrounded.com search for tidio on page source and it's there.

I assumed removing that script code would work. But I can't figure out what file that code is located in. It's not in footer.php

Comment: Have you tried downloading your full site and searching through all the files (with the likes of Notepad++) for tido?

Comment: Yes. I turned indexing on for all files then searched using windows search function. I've also searched a lot of the ones you'd expect using crimson.

Comment: if its not in a add_action / in footer in your active theme or plugins check your cache you may need to clear the cache. `Cached page generated by WP-Super-Cache on 2015-01-20 11:36:34 -->`

Comment: What  do you mean by add_action? I've cleared cache multiple times. even uninstalling wp super cache which does a full cache clear. and then reinstalling it.

Comment: Right.

I have a testing site at olive.ivebeangrounded.com that page source doesn't call the tidio js file. I copied the footer.php file over to the live site and it's still showing. So I'm pretty certain it's not a footer.php file problem

Answer (score 0):

Tidio Developer here. We are adding our js code dynamically via plugin so the only way to remove this behavior is to purge your cache.

Thanks for notice!